# Flex AutoComplete ComboBox?

Tags: apache-flex

I am using FLEX AutoComplete ComboBox,right now it displays the matching options based on the typed input value. is it possible to display the entire list and highlight the matching option based on the user text???

Regards,
Sundar

Answer (score 2):

Sundar

You might want to try the [Flextras](http://www.flextras.com/) AutoCompleteComboBox.  Their control will allow you to filter the list view to those items that match your typed text.  We are using it for our development and it works quite well.

Comment: Thank you for the plug! 

Sundar can accomplish what he wants with our AutoCompleteComboBox by specifying a custom filter filterFunction that returns true to keep all items in the list no matter what the user types.

Comment: is there no alternative (read free) component available that does this?

Comment: @simon: Flextras [seems to be free](http://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=AboutUs), both as in "free speech" and in "free beer".